# How to sort the array in React Hooks using UseState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am Fetching the data from Server and I am having two Objects with "name" and "Money" in the array
Now I need to sort the array by comparing with money field, After trying with below code I am getting
error like "TypeError: Cannot read property 'money' of undefined" , somewhere I facing problem with If condition,

```
const [dataObject, setdataObject] = useState([{}])

  const sortbyRich=()=>{
       
         for(let i=0;i<dataObject.length;i++){
           for(let j=0;j<dataObject.length;j++){
              if(dataObject[j].money < dataObject[j+1].money){
                
                    let temp = dataObject[j];
                    dataObject[j]= dataObject[j+1];
                    dataObject[j+1]= temp;
              }  
           }
         }
       setdataObject(dataObject);
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: Firstly, you are mutating the state. NEVER mutate state in React. Secondly, if your loop reaches the last element in the array, then this code `dataObject[j+1].money` will look for the *next* one, but since there's no next one then `dataObject[j+1]` will be undefined, and you'll get that error. Check if you're at the last element before trying to access the next one

Comment: Or just `const sortByRich = () => setdataObject(prevData => prevData.slice().sort((a, b) => b.money - a.money));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// let's assume you are getting this array of object

let objArr = [
  {name: "Elon", money: 80},
  {name: "Jeff", money: 100},
  {name: "Bill", money: 10}
];

/*
Now just sort it.
For desc sort: objArr.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.money) - parseInt(a.money))
For asc sort: objArr.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.money) - parseInt(b.money))
*/
objArr.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.money) - parseInt(a.money))

console.log(objArr);

/*
OUTPUT:
[
  { name: 'Jeff', money: 100 },
  { name: 'Elon', money: 80 },
  { name: 'Bill', money: 10 }
]

*/

// now use the hook to save sorted data

setObjectdata(objArr);
```

Comment: I am getting the sorted array data in console, But It is not updating the state in browser
I did like this   
dataObject.sort((a,b) => b.money - a.money)
        console.log(dataObject);
        setdataObject(dataObject);

Comment: @Sundeep it's because `sort()` operates in place. As Drew correctly points out, you need to copy the current array before sorting it so that React will correctly update the state.

Comment: Yes it working thanks a lot, Your code solved my Issue

Comment: You would want to memoize the sorted start to avoid re-sorting on each render, only on array changes

Answer (score 4):

The issue is this line

```
if(dataObject[j].money < dataObject[j+1].money){
```

Your initial state is an array with only 1 element in it, so not only by definition is it already sorted, but accessing object properties past the last index `j + 1` will yield an undefined access error.

Use a regular array::sort and pass your own comparator. Use a functional state update, copy the current array, sort in-place and return new sorted array.

Since comparing numbers:

```
setdataObject(data => {
  const dataToSort = [...data];
  dataToSort.sort((a, b) => Number(a.money) - Number(b.money)); // or b.money - a.money to invert order
  return dataToSort; // <-- now sorted ascending
})
```

[image: Edit how-to-sort-the-the-array-in-react-hooks-using-usestate]

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    money: '13.37'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    money: '13.36'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    money: '6.99'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    money: '14'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    money: '0.03'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    money: '6.98'
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [dataObject, setdataObject] = useState(data);

  const sortByRich = () => {
    setdataObject((data) => {
      const dataToSort = [...data];
      dataToSort.sort((a, b) => Number(a.money) - Number(b.money));
      return dataToSort;
    });
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you do this in Stackbiltz , Because when we return dataToSort it is giving me the original array data only not the sorted array data

Comment: @Sundeep that's a tall request considering you haven't provided a [mcve] yourself.

Comment: Here a small mistake is we nee to change parseInt(b.money) - parseInt(a.money)  then Its works for me

Comment: @Sundeep Sure. Updated answer to provide a running codesandbox.